# Force user to populate hyperlink prior to populating a text box

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, hyperlink, vba, ms-access-2016

I'm currently improving a rather old task order database and one of the feature improvements I'm trying to make is to force the user to set a hyperlink value on a form before picking a date for the task to be marked complete.

I am extremely new to vba, btw.

FEDel is my Text box for the date picker.
FSDel is my Control Source for the date picker.
FDLink is my text box for the hyperlink.
LinkToFieldDel is my Control Source for the hyperlink.

```
Private Sub FEDel_Click()
  If LinkToFieldDel = Null Then Msgbox("Please set the Field Deliverables File Path before entering a Delivery Date!", vbCritical, "Field Deliverables File Path Not Set!", "Use the 'Link to File Deliverables' button below to set the file path.") As VbMsgBoxResult


  Exit Sub

Else

End Sub
```

I keep getting a "Compile Error: Statement invalid outside Type block" on LinkToFieldDel and I'm confused as to why that is.

I'm open to any other suggestions on how to make this type of scenario work as well, this is just what came to mind with my limited experience. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few reasons why this won't compile

1. You either have to use your THEN on another line and close your IF
   block after ELSE - or remove the ELSE
2. you should also remove the `As VbMsgBoxResult` - you're calling the function not declaring a sub
3. Remove this unless you have a Help File somewhere "Use the 'Link to File Deliverables' button below to set the file path."

Also - probably a better idea to compare using IsNull() or NZ() functions

```
Private Sub FEDel_Click()

   If IsNull(LinkToFieldDel) Then 
      Msgbox "Please set the Field Deliverables File Path before entering a Delivery Date!", vbCritical, "Field Deliverable File Path Not Set!"         
      Exit Sub

   Else
      ' Do something else here
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Mitch, that worked like a charm! I can't think of an Else action so I removed it.

Comment: Perfect - if you have time mark it as the answer for future looks,